# How to load custom user.config xml into a dictionary

Tags: c#, xml

I need to manually merge older user.config with new settings, and for now I just want to load old values into a dictionary:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <myprog.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="openkey" serializeAs="String">
                <value>o</value>
            </setting> 
            <setting name="licenseAccepted" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
```

Code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(OlderSettingLocation);
XmlNodeList s = document.SelectNodes("/configuration/userSettings/myprog.Properties.Settings/setting");
            foreach (XmlNode node in s)
            {
                myDictionary.Add(node.Attributes["name"].Value, node.Attributes["value"].Value);
            }
```

This results in node.Attributes["name"].Value being "setting" instead of "openkey" in the first loop, and and values are null

Comment: Can you give a more complete sample with multiple settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See code below.  I provided two solutions.  First if each key is unique and second if there are multiple values for each key.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict1 = doc.Descendants("setting").Select(x => new {
                name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                value = (string)x.Element("value")
            }).GroupBy(x => x.name, y => y.value)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());


            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict2 = doc.Descendants("setting").Select(x => new {
                name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                value = (string)x.Element("value")
            }).GroupBy(x => x.name, y => y.value)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

        }
    }
}
```